# Populate associative array using dynamic keys in a loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, key, associative-array

How do I replace the array key of the 2nd array with the value of my 1st Array?

```
$imgNumbers = array();
foreach($imgPat as $imgKey => $imgValue)
{
    $imgNumbers[] = intval(substr($imgValue, strrpos($imgValue, '/') +4));
}


$images = array();
foreach($imgPat as $imgKey => $imgValue) {
    $images[] = img_to_base64($imgValue);
}
```

`$imgNumbers` Returns integers like `2`,`24` or `111`.

and `$images` shall have as an Array key `$imgNumbers`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it in a single loop:

```
$images = array();
foreach($imgPat as $imgKey => $imgValue)
{
    $imgNumbers = intval(substr($imgValue, strrpos($imgValue, '/') +4));
    $images[$imgNumbers] = img_to_base64($imgValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the value of `$imgNumbers` with index as key when second array created

```
 $imgNumbers = array();
    foreach($imgPat as $imgKey => $imgValue)
    {
        $imgNumbers[] = intval(substr($imgValue, strrpos($imgValue, '/') +4));
    }


    $images = array();
    foreach($imgPat as $imgKey => $imgValue) {
        $images[$imgNumbers[$imgKey]] = img_to_base64($imgValue);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to merge them in one loop for better performance, something like this:

```
$imgNumbers = array();
$images = array();
foreach($imgPat as $imgKey => $imgValue)
{
    $imgNumbers = intval(substr($imgValue, strrpos($imgValue, '/') +4));
    $images[$imgNumbers] = img_to_base64($imgValue);
}
```

The previous are more readable but you can decrease the process by merge them and  ignore the $imgNumbers brigde like this:

```
$images = array();
foreach($imgPat as $imgKey => $imgValue)
{
    $images[intval(substr($imgValue, strrpos($imgValue, '/') +4))] = img_to_base64($imgValue);
}
```